# I do not want to use IEEE 802.11b(CCK)

Tags: networking, kernel, wifi, realtek

I am using wifi using rtl8188cus.

I know that the rtl8188cus supports IEEE 802.11b/g/n.

Below is an example of accessing an AP from my system.
SSID: test is an AP that only supports `802.11b(CCK)`.

```
root@test:~# iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11b  ESSID:"test"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 00:26:66:63:1C:54
          Bit Rate:11 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:****-****-****-****-****-****-****-****   Security mode:open
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=97/100  Signal level=-78 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      no wireless extensions.
```

I want the rtl8188cus not to support IEEE 802.11b.

> [Hope]
>       1. I do not want the rtl8188cus to support `IEEE 802.11b`.
>       2. I do not want to use `IEEE 802.11b` when connecting to an IEEE 802.11b/g/n AP.
>       3. When connecting to an AP that supports only `IEEE 802.11b`, it wants the connection to fail.

I looked up the settings related to IEEE 802.11b in my kernel(3.10) but could not find it.
User program(command) did not find a possible way.
I looked into the rtl8188cus driver, but I have not found it either.
I did not find it even after Google.
I tried to comment on rate related stuff in the rtl8188cus driver but it failed.

Can I not just use `IEEE 802.11b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

802.11n and 802.11g are extensions to 802.11b, and include the older protocol. You can't "turn 802.11b off".

Also, your WLAN driver will automatically switch to the bitrate and protocol that works best under the current circumstances given signal strength and channel use. There's a reason for that: If it tried to use a higher bitrate, it would get too many errors, so throughput will decrease with this attempt, not increase.

The signal strength varies a bit with drivers and hardware, but in my experience, your -78 dB are at the edge where communcations ist possible just so.

So if you want higher throughput, find a better place for your antennas, use better antennas, or bring computer and router closer together.

BTW, you can get more detailed information with `iw wlan0 station dump` instead of using the older `iwconfig`.

**Edit**:

Don't say "I am seeing 802.11b bitrates". If you see a bitrate of, say, 11 MB, you still may be connected using protocols as defined by 802.11g or 802.11n, and in fact your WLAN and the access points may have negotiated that bitrate using a protocol that isn't part of 802.11b.

And as I said, 802.11g is an *extension* of 802.11b. 802.11g supports all bitrates and protocol information of 802.11b. 802.11n supports all bitrates and protocol information of both 802.11g and 802.11b. You just usually only see the *new* bitrates in Wikis etc. listed, because repeating the old ones would be tedious.

Comment: Very interesting. Most of the data on the Internet was divided between 802.11b and 802.11 bitrates. Even wikis on the Internet. If 802.11g does not support 802.11b bitrate, is 802.11g wrong?